# Idiom for "I have just finished a great job and I'm proud"

Tags: idiom-request

What is an idiom of:

> "I have just finished a great job and I'm extremely proud of that"

For example, I had been building a house for 20 years and finally built it (and want everybody to know)

I thought "I've done it!" will do, but Google seems not to confirm that. Is there a simple idiom (just an exclamation)?

Comment: Try “I did it!” (instead of “I’ve done it!”) and see if you get better results.

Comment: finished a great job?? or: finishing doing a great job?

Comment: Say, I had been building a house for 20 years and finally built it

Comment: @Serguei: You should have edited that "clarifying" information into your actual question text. I don't think ***nailing it*** would normally be used in the context of ***finally*** finishing something so protracted. But [this related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284186/) essentially confirms my opinion that we don't really have any obvious, widely-recognised idiomatic way of succinctly expressing exactly what you seem to want to say.

Comment: For a long, protracted project that's taken years to complete, the answers will be different than for a more immediate accomplishment. (Ah, question edited while I was commenting. FumbleFingers is right, there isn't really a pithy way to say this that doesn't also have lots of other meanings.)

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that most of the answers below were posted before you edited  your question. I wouldn’t use _smashed, nailed, voila,_ or _there you go_ for something that took 20 years. Too bad you withheld that crucial piece of information for so long.

Comment: Sorry, J.R., I didn't expect that piece to be so important

Comment: Serguei, we can’t read your mind. The single most frustrating thing about being on ELL is learners asking questions as if we charge them by the word.

Comment: One asks questions just because one does not know the answer. And not knowing answers one cannot not know what *is* important in the question and what is not. I believe, it's impossible to correctly answer a question totally without mind-reading

Answer (score 18):

From [AussieEnglish.com](https://theaussieenglishpodcast.com/ep060-expression-to-nail-something-it/) (but as they say in that link, it would be familiar to Anglophones everywhere)...

> **to nail [it / something]**
>    *if you nail something or you nail it in a figurative sense it means that you have completed a task **successfully, perfectly, impressively**, or you’ve gotten something correct, you know, you’ve gotten something right.*

Note - using this idiomatic expression (as in ***I've nailed that tricky job***) doesn't *inherently* include the sense of ***...and I'm proud of having done so***, but in practice that would always be implicit.

---

[image]

Comment: Be aware that this phrase is also often used sarcastically.

Comment: I might have answered or added "mic drop", but that seems to be a faddish saying that has fallen or is falling out of favor. Other than that, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: Nowadays, I see this expression most often in the context of [Pinterest fails](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinterest+fails&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiynJ3jzIPbAhWM6oMKHdPLC4UQsAQIXA&biw=1145&bih=847), but it might actually work for a literal building project with the appropriate imagery. Something like "Nailed it! (And sanded it and plumbed it and electrified it and painted it...)" would make a great housewarming invitation for your finally-finished home.

Answer (score 11):

In English we use a French word:

**voilà!**

In context, its meaning is something like "I've done something pretty good, if I don't say so myself!" or "What I've done is admirable, wouldn't you agree!"

You will actually encounter the word spelled **wa-la** by speakers who have heard it used but have never read it, or if they have read it, have not recognized it.

Comment: I only really know non-negated ***[even] if I say so myself!***. I can't say including ***do*** really strikes me as odd, but the negation certainly does. Is it an AmE/BrE usage split, or perhaps "regional, dialectal"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not sure. Here's a Brit (I believe, though possibly not) who claims that you Brits do say "If I don't say so myself" and an American who doesn't understand that phrase as I do, as set forth in my answer. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/if-i-dont-say-so-myself.388206/

Comment: User Gwennhadu there, who self-identified as "UK English" in his post, specifically says he's always heard it as "non-negated". The one who says "negated or not, they mean the same" is user Isp, whose profile says he's based in NY and deals in US English. I see Google Books claims over a thousand instances of [even though I say so myself](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22even+though+I+say+so+myself%22), but none at all for [even though I don't say so myself](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22even+though+I+don%27t+say+so+myself%22) (which in *some* contexts makes sense!).

Comment: **even though** is not the same as **if** here...

Comment: In AmE you can hear people say, **...and I was pretty darn good at it, if I don't say so MESELF**.  Perhaps they're imitating Irish-English speech?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) has 22 examples of affirmative *if I say so myself*, 60 examples of affirmative *if I **do** say so myself* with *do*-support for emphatic polarity, but only 2 examples of negative *if I do**n't** say so myself*.  So if you don't negate it much over there, I don't think it's an AmE/BrE split.  I don't recall ever having heard the negated version before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The most common phrase is ["If I do say so myself,"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=ds_3Wqb8OIyM8APSzZSYDQ&q=%22if+I+do+say+so+myself%22&oq=%22if+I+do+say+so+myself%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5785.6482.0.6926.3.3.0.0.0.0.115.279.1j2.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.PEshZ0zkgPQ) with 56 thousand Google Books results.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&ei=Zxv4Wvwyq-b9BtCepvgF&q=%22don%27t+say+so+meself%22&oq=%22don%27t+say+so+meself%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13i10i30k1j0i13i5i30k1.4077.6075.0.6277.6.6.0.0.0.0.79.412.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.410...0i13i30k1j0i13i5i10i30k1.0.xeCBGf43Abc

Answer (score 7):

In British casual usage, to emphasise that the task was not merely completed (as "I've done it" might be taken to mean) but done well in a way satisfying to the speaker, people might say I've aced it, I've smashed it, and further intensification is possible by preceding the verb with 'totally', 'completely', etc.

8 guaranteed ways to totally smash your ‘to do’ list in 2015

How I Smashed Out My Christmas Shopping In Two Hours

Since starting with Sustain, I've totally smashed my goals

his sassy kid totally aced his maths test

Comment: I would totally avoid _totally_. At least in the US, it’s become overused and hackneyed. (It’s found in [this list of 12](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/06/09/these-words-are-so-overus_n_5447356.html_), [this list of 9](https://www.forbes.com/sites/robasghar/2013/11/06/9-words-youre-literally-beating-to-death/#464358db18ef), and [this list of 5](http://blog.paperblanks.com/2014/06/writing-wednesday-literally-these-are-actually-the-most-totally-overused-words-of-all-time/) utterly overused words.)

Comment: Yes, I utterly agree.

Comment: "Crushed it" is another variation, but possibly already outdated.  Still, if you're over a certain age, it doesn't matter if you use outdated slang because you already have no hope of being *cool*.  :)

Answer (score 4):

If I have just completed a twenty-year task, my exclamation would most likely be "Finally!", or perhaps "At last!"

If it's not a long, protracted project then the phrases like "Nailed it!" or even "Yesss" would be appropriate.  On short-term achievements I occasionally say "D*mn, I'm good!"

Comment: "Yesss" is quite close to what I'm looking for, but you probably wouldn't send a letter with that  single word to your friend

Comment: In yet another register, "F**k yeah!" would convey the described feeling pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

[**there you go**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there+you+go):

> You're doing that well or correctly; nice job.

Example:

> **There you go!** I knew you'd get the hang of it eventually!

---

This is the context provided by the OP:

> Say, I had been building a house for 20 years and finally built it

Well, then in that case, you could say something like this:

> **Finally done!**

Answer (score 3):

With the caveat that it has acquired an [ironic connotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Accomplished_speech), **mission accomplished** is appropriate for completing a long effort.

Answer (score 2):

(It's) **done and dusted**.‎
‎

> adjective, not comparable
>
> ‎
>   (Britain, idiomatic, of a task) Completed thoroughly and satisfactorily.
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/done_and_dusted)

Answer (score 2):

"I've done it!" has exactly the meaning you are looking for.

In American English, we don't have much in the way of idioms for this, as the previously answers demonstrate: "nailed it" is Australian, I gather "done and dusted" is British, and "voila", from the French, is not really conventional English usage for what you have in mind.

When I completed the requirements for my graduate degree, and got the letter saying I had been approved for graduation, I posted to social networking the single word "Approved" and a photo of the letter.  Everyone got it, and the congratulations came pouring in.  There was no idiom that struck me as more appropriate than that.

Comment: I disagree about the lack of conventional idioms. I'm from the PNW and regularly hear both "nailed it" and "voila". The origin of a phrase doesn't make its use unconventional.

Comment: From the Southwest US, and I can second @JamesMartin... "Nailed it!" and "Voilà!" are, if not used on a daily basis (YMMV), immediately recognizable. "Done and dusted," on the other hand... sounds very British ;)

Answer (score 1):

My Dad would always say "that was a home run" after finishing a big project well or faster than expected. Obviously, this comes from baseball.

Answer (score 1):

'Sorted!'

As SE doesn't like pithy answers, I'll share a story of my late friend 'Kip' Carpenter, creator of the 'Catweazle' character and TV series.  He was looking for a wrap-up line for another script.  Eventually someone suggested 'Sorted!'.   And it was.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catweazle

Answer (score 0):

You raise your fist to the sky and shout "Excelsior!"  It's an English modification of a Latin word and has been used for more than two centuries.

Comment: Will a stranger understand that it's me (or my achievement) are Excelsior, not anybody/anything else?

Comment: It's not an adjective, but rather simply an exclamation.  It popped out of my memory as a cry of glory.  These days it would seem rather quaint, with more than a little humor, but that wouldn't make it any less powerful.  It sounds much less egotistical than saying "I've done it!"

Comment: "Excelsior" means "higher" or "ever higher". It doesn't feel appropriate in this context at all, IMHO.